# C++ Error: Too many initializers for 'int [100]'|

Tags: c++

```
int SUM[100]= {    0,1,5,2,8,3,9,2,8,7,7,
                8,4,7,3,8,4,1,5,4,4,5,
                9,6,2,7,3,6,2,1,1,2,8,
                1,7,2,8,5,9,8,8,9,3,0,
                6,1,7,0,6,5,5,6,2,5,1,
                6,2,9,3,2,2,3,7,4,0,5,
                1,4,0,9,9,0,6,9,5,0,6,
                3,7,6,6,7,1,8,4,9,5,8,
                4,3,3,4,0,3,9,4,0,7,1,
                0,0};
```

If I remove "100" and put "int SUM[]", everything works fine.. Why?

Comment: Reread the error message. It's accurate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because 101 numbers don't fit into a 100 element array.

`int SUM[100];` means that the array has exactly 100 elements, indexed from 0 to **99**. It does *not* mean that 100 is the last valid index! That seems to be a common misconception among beginners.

I always remember it this way: There are 10 digits, namely 0 to 9. But there is no digit 10 :)

Answer (score 4):

```
int SUM[X];
```

This syntax means you have array with X size.

```
int SUM[] = {1,2};
```

This syntax automatically calculate the array size with the number of elements used to initialize it, **e.g** in above example **SUM** size is 2.

In your problem when you provide `100` you are saying allocate array for `100` elements, and when you doesn't provide any number it will automatically compute the elements count and allocate the array size accordingly.
If you calculating elements you are using to fill the array are **101** so to store these  many elements you will required array of size **101**. So either declare `SUM[101]` or leave it empty to auto detection of array size.